# Find all item by custom parameters in a .csv file

Tags: java, csv, java-io

I wrote code and I can save same data in .csv file.[image: Here is a my file's image]

Now i want to read my data from csv file for example by UID.
I tried but can not get all my data by name.
Here is source
Pojo class code

```
public class Product {
private String UID;
private String name;
private String personalNumber;



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "UID='" + UID + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", personalNumber='" + personalNumber + '\'' +

            ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
            ", issueState='" + issueState + '\'' +
            ", documentType='" + documentType + '\'' +
            '}';
}

private String gender;
private String issueState;
private String documentType;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUID() {

    return UID;
}

public void setUID(String UID) {
    this.UID = UID;
}

public String getPersonalNumber() {
    return personalNumber;
}

public void setPersonalNumber(String personalNumber) {
    this.personalNumber = personalNumber;
}


public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getIssueState() {
    return issueState;
}

public void setIssueState(String issueState) {
    this.issueState = issueState;
}

public String getDocumentType() {
    return documentType;
}

public void setDocumentType(String documentType) {
    this.documentType = documentType;
}
```

}
And here is a main java class

```
public class ReadFromFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\\\cardReaderID\\2017-08-31.csv");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);


    Product[] products = new Product[0];
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String UID = input.next();
        String name = input.next();
        String personalNumber = input.next();


        Product newProduct = new Product();
        newProduct.setUID(UID);
        newProduct.setName(name);
        newProduct.setPersonalNumber(personalNumber);
    }

    for (Product product : products) {
        System.err.println(product);
    }


}
```

How I can read all my data from csv file by name? I mean, UID,fullname and etc.
How i can solve my problem?
Thanks everyone

Comment: Are you sure that input.useDelimiter("-|\n") works as you expect?  It's better to use System.getProperty(line.separator) to get the line separator on a particular platform.

Comment: Sorry I mistaked .Removed this line @dsp_user

Comment: Do not parse csv file yourself. There a lot of issues including quotes, line breaks etc. Instead you should use dedicated csv libraries, personally I recommend univocity parsers. Also, take a look on Lombok project, it might simplify your POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
public class CSVReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   String csvFile= "C:\\\\cardReaderID\\2017-08-31.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            System.out.println("Country [code= " + country[4] + " , name=" + country[5] + "]");

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```